# Which grammar generates the language: $L = \{a^i b^j d^k | i, j, k ≥ 0 ∧ j < k\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I am unsure, how can the second answer be the right one - and why not the first one? Can some one explain it step by step?

[image]

Why i think the first answer is right: $aS \to aSA \to aAAd \to abddd$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be the first  because the first grammar generate the word $ddbd\notin \mathcal L$

$$S\to SA \to Sbd \to Adbd \to ddbd$$

Comment: Why do you start with SA? and not aS?

Comment: I don't have to begin $aS$ I can start with $aS$ or $SA$ or $Ad$

Comment: Ok, so the start can be choosed in the way you want to? If so, I think the second grammar is false to?

S --> A --> d ∉ L  (or do I miss something?)

Comment: No, you should start from $S$.

Comment: So for the second you MUST start with S --> aS then  aS --> aA?

Comment: $S \to A \to d \color{red}\in \mathcal L$   Why you are saying that $d$ not in the language? yes it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36032/discussion-between-nehorai-and-martin-andersen).